# Google sheet data reading works on Visual Studio, but it's not working on the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-sheets, asp.net-mvc-4, google-sheets-api

In my ASP.NET project, I have created to get some data from the Google sheet, reading the sheet data.

And when I ran from Visual Studio, 1st time it opened the Google authentication and asked my email address and password.

I provided the same address that I have granted the Google Sheet access to.

Then it started to work fine. So I finished my project and uploaded it to the Azure server.

From there I tried to run the system on the browser and then the authentication window does not open, and no data getting from the sheet.

What could be the problem?

This is my controller code

```
private static UserCredential Login(string googleClientID,string googleClientSecret, string[] scopes)
{
    ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets();
            {
                secrets.ClientId = googleClientID;
                secrets.ClientSecret = googleClientSecret;
            };

    return GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(secrets, scopes ,user:"User",CancellationToken.None).Result;
}
```

```
public ActionResult getStaffMembers() 
{
    try 
    {
        string googleClientID = "clientIDGoesHere.apps.googleusercontent.com";
        string googleClientSecret = "secretIDgoeshere";
        string[] scopes = new [] {
             Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets
        };

        UserCredential credential = Login(googleClientID, googleClientSecret, scopes);

        GoogleSheetManager manager = new GoogleSheetManager(credential);

        var mySpreadSheetID = "spredsheetIDGoesHere";
        var spreadSheet = manager.GetSpreadsheet(mySpreadSheetID);

        string staffMembers = "Staff!A2:A16";
 
        string[] valueRange = new [] { staffMembers };
        var multipleResponse = manager.GetMultipleValues(mySpreadSheetID, valueRange);
        var StaffMemberRange = multipleResponse.ValueRanges.ElementAt(0);

        List<StaffViewModel> records = new List<StaffViewModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < StaffMemberRange.Values.Count; i++) 
        {
            StaffViewModel staffViewModel = new StaffViewModel();
            staffViewModel.Staff_Name = StaffMemberRange.Values[i].First().ToString();
            records.Add(staffViewModel);
        }
        return Json(new { Success = true, StaffList = records }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.Message);
        return Json(new { Success = false }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```